# Scheduled Task Does Not Exist IF It Has a Repeat Trigger

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2016

Since yesterday my task scheduler has been causing some issues here that I was hoping to find some assistance with if possible.
I have a task "TASK" set to run daily each morning and then repeat every 30minutes with the action of launching a batch script from a directory in the C: drive. This script works appropriately when run on its own. When I create a task for the script it will run, unless it is set to have an "After triggered, repeat every X." In this case it gives the error message of: "An error has occurred for task TASK. Error message: The selected task "{0}" no longer exists. To see the current tasks, click Refresh.

I have attempted wiping all tasks from task scheduler and recreating them from scratch, I have wiped the registry of tasks, I have exported and reimported tasks. The issue only occurs when a task is set to repeat after trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Got it myself. Came up with this error due to the fact that the original start date was set to before my attempt at manually running the tasks to test them. Strange.
Solution: Set next start date to the future.